# Do the laws of nested exponentiation hold in groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, solution-verification

Nested Exponentiation (tower of exponents) operation has identity with exponent $a=0$, for any base $g\in \mathbb Z$. Also, exponents are assumed to be integers too.

Also, closure is inherited from integers, as basically multiplication is done, though this is done differently than exponential operation.

Nested Exponentiation operation should be taken as :
$g^{a^{b}}=g^c, c= a^b$

Associative property does not hold as below:

Exponentiation obeys in case of nested exponents, right to left evaluation ordering. Say, $g^{a^{b^{c^{d}}}}$, with $c^{d}= e, b^e= f, a^f= h$. This results in :  $g^{a^{b^{e}}}=g^{a^{f}}=g^h$.

<strike>( It is not true, in general (except for trivial case, when $a=b=c=d$) that $b^e = e^b$, say $b=2, e=3,                                                                                                  b^e= 8, e^b = 9$.)</strike>

If try to change the ordering then results are not same generally, as say $a^{{b^c}^d}\neq a^{b^{c^{d}}}$.

Say, $a=2,b=3, c=4, d=2$. Then, $a^{b^{c^{d}}}=2^{3^{4^{2}}}= 2^{3^{16}}$, but $a^{({b^c})^{d}}=2^{({3^4})^{2}}= 2^{81^{2}}.$

$3^{16} = 3^{4^{4}}$, but $81^2= (3^4)^2$.

So, due to lack of associative property, not possible that nested exponentiation operation forms a group.

Comment: Since the exponent laws amount to just counting the number of times you multiply an element together, yes, the laws hold.  But perhaps that's not what you meant as there's a mis-match between the title and the text of the question.

Comment: @MichaelBurr but in case of nested exponentiation, right to left order the exponents are processed. Or, exponentiation does not cover nested  one? Do you mean title indicates $(a^b)^c= (a^c)^b$? And it can be extended to $3$ or more too, say: $((a^b)^c)^d$? If yes, then is nested exponentiation different category than (normal) exponentiation.

Comment: what do you mean by "closure is inherited from integers"?

Comment: @Max Closure under multiplication, i.e. two integers multiplied yield an integer only.

Comment: @MichaelBurr Is nested exponentiation different operation than exponential operation?

Comment: OK, but if you speak of closure under multiplication of the exponents,  you consider this operation (multiplication of the exponents, and the resulting power laws) rather than the exponentiation of the "base $g\in\Bbb Z$." That multiplication isn't a group because of the 0 which isn't invertible, see also my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean by "exponential operation forms a group"?

Indeed, with "base $g\in\Bbb Z$" it won't work, because elements other than $\pm1$ don't have an inverse here, so negative powers aren't defined.

But for any $g$ in some *group* $G$ (see examples below),
the "exponentiation operation" $e_g: \Bbb Z\to G$, $n\mapsto g^n$, is a group morphism from $(\Bbb Z,+)$ into $(G,\cdot)$. *I.e.*, $e_g(m)\cdot e_g(n)=e_g(m+n)$.

Then you also have $e_g(m)^n = e_{e_g(m)}(n) = e_g(m\,n)$ and as a consequence, the equivalent of the other power laws you quoted.

In view of the fact that exponent 0 (zero) always yields the identity element, and therefore isn't injective and cannot have an inverse operation, one indeed can't get a group in the sense that any exponential operation would have an inverse. (The operation "to the power 0" clearly can't have.) But IMO, the above way of considering exponential operation as a group morphism, comes quite close to saying that it forms a group.

"Appendix": Some examples of groups you might consider:

- the nonzero rationals $\Bbb Q^*$, reals $\Bbb R^*$ or complex numbers $\Bbb C^*$,
- the group GL$_n(R)$ of invertible $n\times n$ matrices with coefficients in some ring $R=\Bbb Z, \Bbb R$...,
- the group of invertible maps $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$, either in the sense of pointwise multiplication (then invertible means nowhere zero) or of composition (then invertible means bijective),
- more generally, the *symmetric group* $S(E)$ of permutations of $E$, *i.e.*, bijections from any $E$ into itself.

Comment: Do you mean that for nested exponentiation, exponents cannot be negative? Am not clear why base cannot be anything apart from $\pm 1$. Please state am example to elaborate.

Comment: When you say "for a base $g\in\Bbb Z$" then (to a mathematician) it means that you consider operations in $\Bbb Z$, where for example 2 has no inverse : $2^{-1}$ does not exist in  $\Bbb Z$ ! So negative exponents are only possible when you are in a group, where every element has an inverse. Indeed, negative powers are explicitly defined as $x^m := (\bar x)^{-m}$ for $m<0$, where $\bar x$ is the inverse of $x$, i.e., such that $x * \bar x = 1$, the identity element in the group. (NB: the set of invertible elements is always a group, even if not all elements are invertible a priori.)

Comment: As you say in your original question, "exponents are assumed to be integers". But when you nest exponents which are negative, the resulting exponent may not be an integer any more, for example, x^(2^(-1)) = x^(1/2) -- you see that you get a non-integral exponent (which you wanted to exclude), and this may be not well defined (for example, when x is a negative real number).

Comment: Regarding your last comment, where you have taken $x$ as real and stated that for fractional exponent (let, $y$), $x^y$ is not well defined; request example. Also, this problem of well-defined doesn't occur for $x$ being integer? Am unclear, as at max. the result of $x^y$ then might be a fraction.

Comment: Regarding your second last comment, have a note at end, that states that : even if not all elements are invertible a priori; still the set of invertible elements is always a group.  Please state the meaning of "a priori" here with some elaboration. Do you mean that some elements are not computed to have beforehand to have inverse, still have the group defined as one of invertible elements.? So, is it an infinite group, generating elements according to some rule that guarantees invertibility of elements?

Comment: Also, for nested exponentiation operation; can the base be $=0$? Am still confused on that part, if needed to be a group.

Comment: For not well defined x^y :  I gave the example : when x is a negative number, for example  x = -1, and y = 1/2, then x^y  = (-1)^(1/2) is not well defined. Yes, for this case we have z = +i = exp( i pi / 2) and z* = -i = exp( - i pi / 2)  which do satisfy z^2 = -1, but still, this ambiguity (2 possible solutions) shows that (-1)^(1/2) is not really well defined.

Comment: Regarding "a priori not invertible": You may have a set S with some multiplication * for which not all elements are invertible. Example : R = the real numbers including 0, or M(n) = square matrices of size n x n. But in both cases you have an identity element 1 for the multiplication. (This is the identity matrix I = diag(1...1) for M(n).) You can consider the **subset** S* of element which do have an inverse:  S* = { x in S : exists y in S : x*y = 1 = y*x }. This subset will always form a group. (In R it is R* = R\{0}, in M(n) it is GL(n) = matrices with invertible determinant,)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137301/discussion-between-max-and-jiten).

Comment: Kindly see my inputs since you left the chatroom. thanks in anticipation of your response.